# separate working path for thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, path

I'm writing a Python script within which I sometimes change directories with `os.chdir(IMG_FOLDER)` in order to do my file operations. That works fine as long as I have one thread only (as I can go back where I came from before leaving the function). Now, in case of multi threading, I would require a seperate "os path" instance for each thread otherwise it might mess up my file operations, hey?
How do I best go about this?

Comment: Have you considered using a sub script or the multiprocessing module?  Both of them start a second interpreter, which can have its own working directory.  Otherwise, just append IMG_FOLDER to the beginning of each of the file operations to do it all by absolute path, via os.path.join or twisted.filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution to this problem was that I

- use absolute paths, no more relative as suggested by Perkins
- when data is being received in my main thread I write it to data `.tmp` e.g. and only once the write process is completely finished, it'll be renamed to the name, that I'm scanning for in the seperate thread.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `os.chdir`. Instead, use `os.path.join` to form full paths.